# Repository for large binary files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am looking for a cloud  architecture to satisfy the following requirements for a file repository for a research project  :
1. A file repository that can hold large files ( total size of 0.5 TB ) 
2. can be accessed easy for analysis ( running some script to read data from the binary files). 
3. The files are read only so no versioning is required.

I thought of using AWS  or Google cloud for this but i am not sure of which modules should i use to achieve the above

Comment: Take a look at Amazon S3.